# What did Hashem sound like?

Tags: theology, moshe-rabbeinu, nevua-prophecy, hearing

Is there any source for what Hashem's voice sounded like when he spoke to Moshe Rabeinu? Like was it a man's voice or a woman's voice? Gruff or sweet? What type of accent? Middle Eastern,Ashkenaz, European?

Comment: Kol D'mama Daka?

Comment: Are you only asking about what hebe sounded like to Moshe in particular, and not to anyone else? If so, consider editing your title to clarify.

Comment: well the speaking was def not typical...שמור וזכור בדיבור אחד.....

Comment: Mark, likely it wasn't in any accent we're familiar with, due to changes in pronunciation of Hebrew between Yetziat Mitzrayim and the ba'alei Mesorah. While the accents of the ba'alei Mesorah are fairly familiar to us, as they reflect few differences with Teimanit (excepting vowel representation and the lack of jimmel גּ) what I've heard about biblical Hebrew from friends who are better read than I is that there are some things we'd never recognise, like שׂ being pronounced þ.

Comment: I question if there really is a concept of G-d's "voice". Ramba"m and I believe Ramcha"l, among others explain that G-d has no human form and therefore doesn't "speak". Tanac"h mentions G-d speaking so that when humans read this, we can understand things in human terms. But, in actuality, it's possible that Moshe and others "comprehended" as message  as if G-d were talking to them. If you really must know what G-d sounds like watch how Burt Lancaster reacts when he hears G-d's voice ;-)

Comment: There's some commentary about how God spoke to Moshe at the burning bush, but I don't know of anything that addresses your broader question.  (Doesn't mean it doesn't exist; there're lots of things I don't know.)

Comment: @DanF Your comment (less the last sentence) looks to me like an answer.

Comment: The question explicitly asks for sources. Why are people voting to close as primarily opinion based?

Comment: Does G-d have an accent? A voice even?

Answer (score 11):

See the Medrash Raba on Shemos (Exodus) [פרשה ג](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01634_part_1.html#HtmpReportNum0002_L2) that states that (at least initially, at the burning bush) Hashem sounded just like Moshe's father Amrom when He spoke to him.

> אָמַר רַבִּי יְהוֹשֻׁעַ הַכֹּהֵן בַּר נְחֶמְיָה בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁנִּגְלָה הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא עַל משֶׁה טִירוֹן הָיָה משֶׁה לַנְּבוּאָה, ‏
> אָמַר הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא "אִם נִגְלָה אֲנִי עָלָיו בְּקוֹל גָּדוֹל אֲנִי מְבַעֲתוֹ, בְּקוֹל נָמוּךְ בּוֹסֵר הוּא עַל הַנְּבוּאָה", ‏
> מֶה עָשָׂה? **נִגְלָה עָלָיו בְּקוֹלוֹ שֶׁל אָבִיו**, ‏
> אָמַר משֶׁה "הִנֵּנִי! מָה אַבָּא מְבַקֵּשׁ?", ‏
> אָמַר הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא "אֵינִי אָבִיךָ אֶלָּא אֱ-לֹהֵי אָבִיךָ, בְּפִתּוּי בָּאתִי אֵלֶיךָ כְּדֵי שֶׁלֹא תִּתְיָרֵא"‏

Similarly we find that when He (first) spoke to Shmuel, it sounded like Eili Hakohen's voice.

Comment: Is there anything we can infer from this, or some other source, that would indicate a general rule of what G-d sounded like to various people, such as Avraham, Yitzhak, etc.? Also, even with Moshe, did G-d change his voice? E.g., even in the initial conversation, G-d is angry with Moshe. Did that sound like Amram being angry, or did G-d's voice change in the middle?

Comment: @DanF - Good question. Still looking and learning. That's why I was careful to write _initially_. :-)

Answer (score 9):

Midrash Tehilim 18:29 (in the name of R. Luliani) says that Hashem spoke with Moshe with the voice of Moshe himself:

> רבי לוליאני בשם רבי ישמעאל אמר בנוהג שבעולם הרב אומר והתלמיד עונה. אבל
>   הקב"ה אינו כן (שם יט יט) משה ידבר והאלקים יעננו בקול. הוי וענותך תרבני

Seems that the any other characteristics mentioned when applied to G-d's voice deppends on the person's ability with whom Hashem speaks. The posuk in Shemos 20:15 says: "And all the people saw the voices". The **Pesiqta Hadeta** (Bes Hamidrash 6:39) notes: "Here it's not said "voice" but "voices", implying that  each and every individual hear the voice of G-d.

**Shemos Rabbah 29:1** says that they heard the voice accordingly his or her ability.

> ר' לוי ופירשה, אמר להם: השמע עם קול אלהים, כיצד? אילו היה כתוב קול ה'
>   בכחו, לא היה העולם יכול לעמוד, אלא קול ה' בכח, **בכח של כל אחד ואחד.
>   הבחורים לפי כחן, והזקנים לפי כחן, והקטנים לפי כחן.** אמר הקב"ה לישראל:
>   לא בשביל ששמעתם קולות הרבה, תהיו סבורין שמא אלוהות הרבה יש בשמים, אלא
>   תהיו יודעים שאני הוא ה' אלהיך, שנאמר (שם ה): אנכי ה' אלהיך:

**Pesikta dRav Kahana, Piska 12** says:

> לוי נראה להם הקב"ה כאיקונין הזו שיש לה פנים מכל מקום אלף בני אדם
>   מביטין בה והיא מבטת בכולם כך הקב"ה כשהיה מדבר **כל אחד ואחד מישר' היה
>   אומ' עמי הדבר מדבר אנכי י"י אלהיכם אין כת' כאן אלא אנכי י"י אלהיך
>   (שם)**
>
> When the HKBH spoke, each and every person in Israel could say, “The
>   Divine Word is addressing me.” Note that Torah does not say, “I am the
>   Lord your (pl.) God,” but I am the Lord your (sing.) G-d.

That's why, according other sources (the one quoted earlier by @Danny Schoemann for example), G-d's voice sounded familiar to the person who is adressed, like Moshe's father, Eli Hakohen, and so on...